# Test methods not executing on sandbox org while deploy metadata

Tags: deployment, ant-script, mdapideploy

I'm trying to run ant command - deploy and deployCodeCheckOnly - on my sandbox org. In both targets, `testLevel` attribute value is `RunSpecifiedTests` and `RunLocalTests`.

Commands executed successfully and code deployed/validated on the sandbox org without executing the test methods.

Could anyone please help me in order to resolve this issue fast?

Comment: Did you mention the test class names which needs to be run in xml file ?

Comment: Yes, I've added test class names when I executed RunSpecifiedTests command.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mention the test class names in `build.xml` file which you want to run.

Your `build.xml` file should have the test class names like below, you can replace the name of the target and test class names that matches your requirement.

```
<target name="deployCode">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
           sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
        <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
<target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
           sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" checkOnly="true">
        <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

You can refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) salesforce document for further help on this topic.

Comment: Hello Vijay, I've tried this option but it has not worked for me.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/262975/edit) your question to include the build.xml file's content as well.

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj Is this how your `build.xml` file's content look like ?

Comment: Hi @VijayGanji, Yes it looks like the same. I've opened a case with Salesforce and it seems they can fix this issue internally. I'll update once I receive any update.

Comment: Hi @VijayGanji, Yes we need to contact with Salesforce in order to enable this feature. This is something which they manage internally. My problem is now resolved.